# JAXP: How to force XPath to validate namespace prefixes?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xpath, jaxp

I am relying on the **default JAXP implementation** and using the **Oracle JRE**.
When evaluating a XPath which contains an unknown namespace prefix, it does not throw an (expected) exception.

When I run the same application on an **IBM JRE, everything is fine** and it throws the expected exception `javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: org.apache.xpath.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace`

I am using the following code which tries to access an **invalid namespace unknownns**

```
  DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
      .newInstance();

  documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(true);
  documentBuilderFactory.setAttribute(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA);

  DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

  Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile_);

  XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
  NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("path/to/node/unknowns:@bla", doc,
      XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Question:

**How can I enforce this validation independently from the JAXP implementation?**

Comment: Can you post the code responsible for initializing and configuring the DocumentBuilderFactory instance, and the XPathFactory and XPath instances?

Comment: What is the class of the object that XPathFactory.newInstance() returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [setting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext%28javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext%29) a `NamespaceContext` on your `XPath` instance:

```
public final class NSValidator {
  private NSValidator() {
  }

  private static final NamespaceContext INSTANCE = new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
      return Collections.emptyList()
          .iterator();
    }
  };

  public static NamespaceContext noNamespaces() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. It seems that the IBM JRE has a default NamespaceContext, while the Oracle JRE has not. Latter causes that errors related to contexts will not be reported by default.